# Buttons group, position relative, above footer

Tags: html, css

I wonder if it is possible in a relative position, to stick the three buttons just above the footer.
I don't want to change the flex display. Any ideas?

```css
.buttons-group {
    display: flex;
}

#button1, #button2, #button3 {
    color: #111;
  width: 100%;
    height: 35px;
    color: #111;
    border: 1px solid #3c7da0;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    font-size: 12px;
    text-align: center;
    outline:none;
    text-decoration:none;
 }
#button1:hover, #button2:hover, #button3:hover {
  background: orange;
}

.footer {
   position: fixed;
   left: 0;
   bottom: 0;
   width: 100%;
   background: grey;
   color: white;
   text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="buttons-group">
  <button id="button1">One</button>
  <button id="button2">Two</button>
  <button id="button3">Three</button>
</div>

<div class="footer">
  <p>Copyright @2021. All rights reserved</p>
</div>
```

Comment: I mean I don't want ie display:inline-block etc.. I use flex in my project. Is it possible? Do you have any idea? Thanks a lot!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need another level of flex--one for the overall layout. This way you don't need to use fixed positioning for the footer.

```css
body, .page {
  min-height: 100vh;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  background: pink;
}

.page {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: end;
}

.buttons-group {
  display: flex;
}

#button1,
#button2,
#button3 {
  color: #111;
  width: 100%;
  height: 35px;
  color: #111;
  border: 1px solid #3c7da0;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  font-size: 12px;
  text-align: center;
  outline: none;
  text-decoration: none;
}

#button1:hover,
#button2:hover,
#button3:hover {
  background: orange;
}

.footer {
  background: grey;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="page">
  <div class="buttons-group">
    <button id="button1">One</button>
    <button id="button2">Two</button>
    <button id="button3">Three</button>
  </div>

  <div class="footer">
    <p>Copyright @2021. All rights reserved</p>
  </div>
</div>
```